# What's the best way to process strings for inputs in Keras?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a dataset where name is an important feature . I want to use it has an input node in my keras neural network in python . But since this is not possible , what's the best way to do it ??

I have tried one hot encoding but since the length of the name is not fixed , it is not useful ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Embeddings](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding), which translates large sparse vectors (one-hot encoded) into a lower-dimensional space that preserves semantic relationships. So for the categorical feature, you will have dense vector representation.

```
unique_amount = np.unique(col1)
input_1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='input_1')
embedding_1 = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(unique_amount_1, 50, trainable=True)(input_1)
col1_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(embedding_1)
```

Where `50` - the size of the embedding vector, that you can choose by your self.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `character` level one hot encoding as follows in `keras`. Make sure you set `char_level=True` flag in `Tokenizer`. This could leads us very low dimension sparse matrix.

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer(char_level=True)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(<names>)
sequence_of_int = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(<dataset_names>)
```

Even, you try with representing frequency based character encoding by your own.